# Can I determine whether a property setter is internal or not?

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

I have a set of properties, some of them have `private` setter and some of them have `internal` setter. Is there any way that at runtime I can check whether setter of a property is `internal` or not?

Comment: @jon doesn't [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isassembly.aspx) tell you what you need to know?

Comment: @Jon well wouldn't the answer disagree?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: You are right. Thanks for the refresher :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this info using reflection:

```
var myType = obj.GetType();
var setMethod = myType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
                      .GetSetMethod(true);
bool isInternalSetter = setMethod != null && setMethod.IsAssembly;
```